# how to split a large csv writing to several files by multiple processing in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv, multiple-processes

I have a very large csv file (40G), and I want to split it into 10 df by column and then write each to csv file (about 4G each). To save time, I choose multiple processing to process it. But I found the mp doesn't work, it still processes one by one. I wonder if we cannot write large files by mp?
here my code goes:

```
def split(i, output_path, original_large_data_path):
    data = pandas.read_csv(original_large_data_path) #read in the large data
    new_data = data[i].dropna(how = 'all', subset = [i]) #split the data and drop na based on seperated df
    new_data.to_csv(os.path.join(output_path, '{}.csv'.format(i)) #write csv
    
pool = Pool(5)
for i in [some columns]:
    r = pool.apply_async(split,(i,output_path, original_large_data_path,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Are you saying that the output CSVs each have just one column?

Comment: I mean the csv files are outputted one by one, although I use mp expecting they are outputted at the same time.

Comment: If you look at my answer you will see how you can do this using multiprocessing. However, you should note that pandas will read the entire source file into memory and, given the size of the file, you may run into performance issues anyway due to swapping.

Answer (score 0):

Use map, partial and a context manager as follows:

```
import pandas
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

INFILE = '' # Path to input file
OUTPATH = '' # target directory

def split(infile, outpath, col):
    data = pandas.read_csv(infile)
    new_data = data[col].dropna(how = 'all', subset = [col])
    new_data.to_csv(os.path.join(outpath, f'{col}.csv'))

def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(partial(split, INFILE, OUTPATH), range(10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```